# Simple tagging ability to rapidly change document properties

Tags: tags, windows-11

I was very disappointed to find that the simple features in my previous Windows computer for tagging my photos is no longer available on Windows 11. Previously, an option was available in the details pane to add tags. The workflow to right-click file, then navigate to the Details tab and then select the tag box adds considerable time when I need to add tags to hundreds of photos. In addition to managing my files within my own computer, the tags are very useful when uploading my image files to iNaturalist, which automatically detects tags and uses them to add the species name to the observations. Thus, the solution needs to directly modify the file properties in a way that iNaturalist can recognize and cannot only exist within the software.

I have tried `tagspaces`, `tagging for windows` and `tag explorer`. All three applications allow for adding tags to files within the software. However, the tags are not exported to the file outside the software and the tags are not applied to the document properties. If there is a way to copy those tags outside the software to the file properties, I would be very pleased.

**I am looking for a tagging solution that provides a direct box when viewing an image in which to type in the tags (and the tags need to allow for spaces, e.g. "Kalmia angustifolia"), which also directly modifies the file properties.**

Comment: For photos an Windows shell extension that allows to edit Exif data would be what you are searching for. Unfortunately all the Exif tools I know are stand-alone, thus not integrated into Win Explorer.